# Pack/unpack array of binary data

Tags: perl, binary, integer, pack

I have an array of unsigned integers (32 bits) that I want to [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) into a binary stream:

```
my @n = (4,8,15,16,23,42);
my $foo = join('', map(pack('I', $_), @n)); # Ugly, isn't?
```

`$foo` should contains this binary stream (depending on the endianness)

```
0000000 0000 0004 0000 0008 0000 000F 0000 0010
0000010 0000 0017 0000 002A
```

Then I would like to [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) the binary stream back to an array.

How do I properly do it with Perl and if possible with only built-in modules?

Comment: The variables `$a` and `$b` are reserved for use in `sort` blocks and it's considered bad practice to use them for anything else.

Comment: Good point! I will use $foo $bar instead :)

Comment: Removing the unnecessary parens would have helped too. `join '', map pack('L', $_), @nums;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is

```
my $packed = pack('I*', @nums);   # unsigned int (varies in size)
my $packed = pack('L*', @nums);   # uint32_t
```